# ADAL.js - "Nonce is not same as undefined"

Tags: javascript, azure, single-page-application, azure-active-directory, adal

I am currently having trouble with the ADAL.js (v1.0.7) library. When I load my app after a decent period of time I get a login error stating "Nonce is not same as undefined." After looking over the code, I am wondering if I am missing a best practice. To my knowledge, I have followed the suggestions of @vibronet [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/). Should I be refreshing the user profile, or logging out, or something else?

My configuration looks like:

```
        window.config = {
        instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
        tenant: 'blahblahblah.onmicrosoft.com',
        clientId: 'GUID',
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
    };

    this.authContext = new window.AuthenticationContext(window.config);
    var isCallback = this.authContext.isCallback(window.location.hash);
    this.authContext.handleWindowCallback();

    if (isCallback && !this.authContext.getLoginError()) {
        window.location = this.authContext._getItem(this.authContext.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.LOGIN_REQUEST);
    }
```

If there has been an extended period of inactivity, the error occurs after calling this.authContext.login(). In order to get the error I call this.authContext.getLoginError().

I get why the nonce is different, but I want to "reset" it or cause a brand new login to happen.

Please let me know what other relevant information I can provide.

Comment: will be good if you can include some code. otherwise will be hard to see what was wrong.

Comment: I've edited the original post to add more detail.

Comment: Also if I clear the localStorage for the site, then it works as it should.

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Update:

Seems like solution has been provided in blog post you provide. below is the quote.

> The trick is to go back to the authority asking for a token, like we’d
>   do in the roundtrip apps scenario, but doing so in a hidden iframe. If
>   there is still an existing session with the authority (which might be
>   represented by a cookie – but it is a cookie in the domain of the
>   authority, NOT the app’s) we will be able to get a new token without
>   any UX. There is even a specific parameter, prompt=none, which lets
>   Azure AD know that we want to get the token without a UX, and if it
>   can’t be done we want to get an error back. Here there’s the request.

Previous answer:

i am not fully follow what your code does. but as from blog post, seems like underneath you are using OAuth 2.0

when you said error happen when there is period of inactivity, my guess is token has been invalid, and you will need to refresh the token. Not sure if there is a way for you to refresh it. But normally on server side once you authenticated, OAuth 2.0 provider will hand over you a token and a refresh token, if token is expired, you can use refresh token to get a new one.

Comment: Right, its my understanding that when you make a call to authContext.login(), that the function call would handle this automatically. Instead when I make a call to that function I get an error explaining that the nonce token is not correct. Is there some other call in this library that I should be making?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge they are correct. If I change them, then I am not able to authenticate at all.

Comment: ah i see. so you mean after you authenticate and you try to login again you see that error. then it is back to my answer, you will have to renew your credential yourself. i don`t think the login function will do the job for you.

Comment: Right. I am not sure how to do that without making a call to authContext.login(). From my understanding of it, the login() method is supposed to automatically handle renewing the credential on its own. Interestingly enough, if I clear the localStorage for my site, then it will work and renew correctly. So there is a problem with the old nonce token in the store. I guess I could manually remove it, but I feel like the library is supposed to handle that without my input.

Comment: right, your suggestion seems valid to me. ADAL.js seems like it is an opensource project. try to make your suggestion to them here https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js

Comment: Thanks, just commented here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/216

Comment: Has anyone solved this problem? How can I get the correct nonce? Or how long does it take for nonce to expire, how can I know that it is expired?