# adal.js inifnite loop when refreshing token

Tags: adal.js

I am using the latest adal.js to query data from MicroSoft Dynamics CRM. The code gets into an infinite loop when renewing the token.

Additionally after loging into microsoft and being redirected back to my page the adaljs tries to refresh the token.

Note - this is javascript in an ASP.NET MVC web app. It is **not** using angular js.

This is also similar to the SO question [Adal & Adal-Angular - refresh token infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211367/adal-adal-angular-refresh-token-infinite-loop)

```
var endpoints = {
    orgUri: "https://<tenant>.crm6.dynamics.com/"
};

var config = {
    clientId: 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    tenant: '<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:53290/home/AuthenticatedByCrm/',
    endpoints: endpoints,
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
};
var x = new AuthenticationContext(config);

var isCallback = x.isCallback(window.location.hash);

if (isCallback) {
    x.handleWindowCallback();
    x.acquireToken(endpoints.orgUri, retrieveAccounts);
} else {
    x.login();
}

function retrieveAccounts(error, token) {
    // Handle ADAL Errors.
    if (error || !token) {
        alert('ADAL error occurred: ' + error);
        return;
    }

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", encodeURI(organizationURI + "/api/data/v8.0/accounts?$select=name,address1_city&$top=10"), true);
    //Set Bearer token
    req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 /* complete */) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status == 200) {
                var accounts = JSON.parse(this.response).value;
                //renderAccounts(accounts);
            }
            else {
                var error = JSON.parse(this.response).error;
                console.log(error.message);
                //errorMessage.textContent = error.message;
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for JavaScript](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) helps you to use Azure AD for handling authentication in your single page applications. **This library is optimized for working together with AngularJS**.

Based on the investigation, this issue is caused by the `handleWindowCallback`. The response not able to run into the branch for `if ((requestInfo.requestType === this.REQUEST_TYPE.RENEW_TOKEN) && window.parent && (window.parent !== window))` since it is not used in the Angular enviroment.

To integrate Azure AD with MVC application, I suggest that you using the **[Active Directory Authentication Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/)**. And you can refer the code sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web.git).

### Update

```
if (isCallback) {
     // x.handleWindowCallback();
     var requestInfo=x.getRequestInfo(window.location.hash);
     //get the token provided resource. to get the id_token, we need to pass the client id
     var token = x.getCachedToken("{clientId}")
     x.saveTokenFromHash(requestInfo);            
} else {
    x.login();
}
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that Active Directory Authentication Library you are referring to is for c# and not JavaScript? Is it possible to use ADAL for a single page application that does not use angular from JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, the second link above is used for .Net application. It is possible using the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for JavaScript for a single page application. Please check the updated code in the post.

Comment: How do I get the token after saving it? I need a line of code like var token = x.getToken();

Comment: The ADAL provided `getCachedToken` method to get the token from catch based on the resource.  And to get the id_token, we can pass the `client id` to this method. Hope it is helpful.